# How can I use user "profile" module with "multiple registration" module in drupal 8? remove profile form duplicacy

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

How can I split / specify / re-position the "profile" module forms with "show in registration" active and with 'Multiple Registration' module into different tabs.

[two module integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H4IG.png)

I hope the image explains my problem. I don't want to show doctors profile form in institutes tab and vice versa.

I have never done anything in drupal using code so if the solution can only be achieved using code also link or specify how to do it. I have been using UI to place and edit blocks and everything in drupal for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [form modes](https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/provide-custom-mode-form-entities-drupal-8) to create dedicated forms with different fields for your users (ie. institute / doctors / ancillary).

Comment: Okay, but I ended up doing the regular way i.e. adding fields to people/account_settings/manage_fields yeah I removed "profile" module and limited fields to certain roles using "multiple_registration" and that is what I hate a bit all the fields for different roles are messed up in a single page while managing but while displaying